# Expire Output Cache ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I am using the standard outputcache tag in my MVC app which works great but I need to force it to be dumped at certain times.  How do I achieve this?  The page that gets cached is built from a very simple route {Controller}/{PageName} - so most pages are something like this: /Pages/About-Us

Here is the output cache tag that is at the top of my .aspx view page just to be clear:

```
<@ OutputCache Duration="100" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

So in another action on the same controller where content is updated I need to dump this cache, or even all of it - it's a very small app so not a big deal deal to dump all cached items.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Be careful about using "None" vs. "".

- If you send "" then the HttpHeader for [Vary](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/vary-header.html) is *not* sent.
- If you send "None" then the HttpHeader for [Vary](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/vary-header.html) *is* sent.

I used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddle2.com/) to verify this behavior.

This seems to have an impact on whether or not the browser goes back to the server to check for latest version (causing a 304). At least in Chrome it does. You want to use `Varies=""` if you know for sure you aren't going to want to update the file before it has expired.

I'd recommend using `Varies=""` as I did in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486063/what-clever-things-have-you-done-with-an-asp-net-mvc-actionresult). For my javascript file I dont want the browser going back and making another Http request until it has expired. 304 is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, what's up with this? Why does it send "Vary: *" if you set VaryByParam to "none"?

Comment: i'm still confused about this!

Comment: confirmed, when you do `Varies="none"` you get the header `Vary: *` in the response. When you do `Varies=""` you get no such header.

Comment: @jeff thanks for the confirmation. every time i end up back at my own post here i get confused and dubious about what i wrote. hope you'll post any more in depth findings back

Comment: Or, to remove Vary: *, use this.Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);

Comment: @KevinHakanson: Alternatively, set it for your whole app in your `web.config`: `<caching><outputCache omitVaryStar="true" /></caching>`.

Comment: This is useful information, but it doesn't seem to answer the question asked, at least not without some context. @Slee, did you combine this answer with info from another one? If so, we should edit this answer to contain the necessary more-basic-info. How DO you dump the output cache? And how does "being careful about None vs """ relate to this question?

Comment: @Seth Was going to post the same thing... how is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 15):

`HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem()` is probably the method you want to use.  If you can figure out what name the actions are cached under, you can remove just the specific action (try setting a breakpoint or dumping all of the names of cached items to the screen)

Otherwise, I'd iterate through the entire output cache and just clear every item.

Answer (score 7):

Not knowing the difference between "None" and "" for the VaryByParam, I was using this attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Location=OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, Duration=int.MaxValue, VaryByParam="none")]
```

And this code to "fix" the `Vary: *` problem:

```
this.Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
```

Which I found referenced at [ASP.NET caching tests find a bug with VaryByParam](http://www.andypotts.com/Blog/CommentView,guid,05dcac0c-1d46-42ba-8d3c-b2eb5b36b45a.aspx)

> The difference between a OutputCache
>   directive set to "Client" and
>   "ServerAndClient" is that
>   "ServerAndClient" outputs the Vary
>   field. This is impacting IE in that IE
>   is sending requests regardless. 
>   The use of the vary:* header can disable
>   all client caching
>   (http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setomitvarystar.aspx).
>
> The only way to remove the vary:* header and thus allow client caching was through code:

Answer (score 1):

it seems that output cache doesn't put anything in HttpContent.Cache because when I loop through it the collection is empty:

```
For Each elem As DictionaryEntry In HttpContext.Cache
  HttpContext.Cache.Remove(elem.Key)
Next
```

Here is my action attribute:

```
<OutputCache(Duration:=600, VaryByParam:="pagename")> _
Function Index(ByVal pagename As String) As ActionResult
```

Comment: Aren't HttpContext.Cache and the OutputCache different?  I could be wrong, but your example is dealing with the HttpContext.Cache.

Comment: @Zach Yes, they have no real relation.