# Caching until data changes in ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, entity-framework-4.1, outputcache

I currently use the repository pattern in my ASP.NET MVC 3 app.

I use OutputCache to lessen the load on my database by decorating my controller methods with a data annotation similar to this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "userName")]
```

Ultimately, what I'd like to achieve is a level of caching whereby the data is cached until it is updated (i.e. it changes).  I am using Entity Framework 4.1 for ORM.

What would be the recommended way to approach this using my selected stack?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expire Output Cache ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376851/expire-output-cache-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: How will you know when your data is updated? If you are assuming that you will manage the state of an object by using your controllers you could manipulate the cache:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585/clearing-page-cache-in-asp-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.85).aspx

There's a SqlDependency attribute :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

A custom provider would be the only way.