# Vary: * incorrectly added to http header response (asp.net mvc3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers, outputcache, appharbor

I am using the following output cache profile:

```
<add name="MyFunkyProfile" duration="180" varyByParam="*" location="ServerAndClient" />
```

In dev, I have a response header with one Vary entry:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
...
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: private, max-age=180, s-maxage=0
...
```

When I deploy my app, I have an extra Vary entry inserted in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
...
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: private, max-age=180, s-maxage=0
...
Vary: *
...
```

Why this extra Vary entry? This is preventing the cache from working correctly.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `varyByParam` to `None` in your profile/config file? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx.

Also, just guessing here - does the config file differ between dev and 'live', e.g. `varyByParam` may be set differently?

*Note: I've just joined SO so can't add comments just yet (which I would have done instead of posting this as a reply).*

Comment: Can't set varyByParam to None this will yield wrong results. No the varyByParam is set in the same way in dev and prod. The server is different though; dev server vs IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The `Vary: Accept-Encoding` header is inserted by the AppHarbor routing layer. The header is necessary to get downstream proxies (typically a CDN like AWS CloudFront or similar) to correctly cache both gzip'ed and non-gzip'ed versions of your content. This [question has additional details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848796/what-does-varyaccept-encoding-mean).

Can you detail how this is causing problems for your application?

Comment: Vary star is inserted by the framework by default unless varyByParam="" is specified (notice that varyByParam="*" still generates vary star) see Atwood's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/486072/125804 . Worked around the problem. Will post the workaround here as answer.